# How to add jtextfield values to a constructor and an arraylist?

Tags: java, string, swing, arraylist

When a user clicks the "add" button, the program is meant to get the values from the jtextfields and then setting it to the constructor. After adding the constructor to an arraylist. Then iterating through the arraylist and printing the values.

I don't get any errors, but I get null values.

```
String title = textfield1.getText();
String author = textfield2.getText();

Book b = new Book(title, author);
lib.addBook(b);

System.out.println(b);
```

I have 3 classes. Book, Library, and Test

Test

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class Test extends JFrame{

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Book");
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    private JLabel label2, label3;

    private JTextField textfield1, textfield2;

    private JButton button1;

    static Library lib = new Library();

    void form(){

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   
    panel.setLayout(null);


    label2 = new JLabel("title:");
    label2.setBounds(9, 61, 123, 13);
    panel.add(label2);

    label3 = new JLabel("author:");
    label3.setBounds(9, 91, 123, 13);
    panel.add(label3);


    textfield1 = new JTextField(10);
    textfield1.setBounds(121, 63, 125, 21);
    panel.add(textfield1);

    textfield2 = new JTextField(10);
    textfield2.setBounds(121, 93, 125, 21);
    panel.add(textfield2);


    button1 = new JButton("Add");
    button1.setBounds(351, 226, 125, 21);
    panel.add(button1);


    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setSize(545,540);
    frame.setVisible(true);


    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public  void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    String title = textfield1.getText();
    String author = textfield2.getText();

    Book b = new Book(title, author);
    lib.addBook(b);

    System.out.println(b);



    }
    });





    }

    public static void main(String [] args){

        Test a = new Test();
        a.form();
        }


     }
```

Library

```
 import java.io.Serializable;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Iterator;
 import java.util.List;

 public class Library{

    private List<Book> list = new ArrayList<Book>();

    public void addBook(Book b){
        list.add(b);
    }

    public String toString() {          
        String total = "\n";            
        Iterator<Book> i = list.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext()){
            Book b = (Book) i.next();
            total = total + b.toString();
        }
        return total;
    }    
}
```

Book

```
 public class Book{

    private String title;
    private String author;

    public Book(){

    title = "";
    author = "";
    }

    public Book(String title, String author){           
         title = title;
         author = author;       
      }

    public String getTitle(){
        return title;   
    }
    public void setTitle(String title){
        title = title;  
    }
    public String getAuthor(){
        return author;
    }
    public void setAuthor(String author){
        author = author;
    }    

    public String toString(){
        return  "Title: " + getTitle() + "\n" + 
                "Author: " + getAuthor() + "\n";        }   
}
```

Comment: Where in your code do you iterate through the ArrayList? I don't see this. What line gives you null values?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is bad:

```
public Book(String title, String author){

title = title;
author = author;

}
```

You're just setting the parameter to itself.  Instead use `this` to set the actual class fields:

```
public Book(String title, String author){    
   this.title = title;
   this.author = author;    
}
```

The more important lesson to be gained here: continually test your classes and your code in isolation before putting it all together. If you had written a small main method in the Book class to test it out, you'd have found the error.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: and ditto, 1+ to you.

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem lies here...

```
public Book(String title, String author){

    title = title;
    author = author;

}
```

You are simply assigning the parameters back them selves, which means the member/instance variables will still be `null`

Try using the `this` keyword to assign the parameters to the member variables

```
public Book(String title, String author){

    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;

}
```

Check out [Using the this Keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) for more details...

Comment: @user2994263 Makes a nice change ;)